# Elasticsearch: Find out primary shards' running node name?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose an elasticsearch index has 5 primary shards and 2 replica shards for each of the primary shards. Also there are 3 active nodes in the running cluster. How can I find out which primary shards is on which node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cat api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-shards.html) with shards as parameter to get the required details.

For e.g. if one of you node is running on localhost port 9200, you can use the below:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v
```